# How to calculate the total locked XTZ?

Tags: baking, protocol

Using the TZscan.io Stats - Key Numbers dashboard, how can I calculate the total locked XTZ in the system? And shouldn't this be a KPI measure by itself? Since delegators can very easily move their XTZ I don't consider that locked, especially since all the exchanges will be auto delegating for their account holders.

```
Total frozen balances
Total frozen deposits
Total frozen rewards
Total frozen fees
——-
Total Frozen XTZ ?
```

Also, what is the difference between 'Total frozen deposits' and 'Total frozen balances'?

Comment: Please clarify if you want to know how total locked for every baker or for one address. Also "Total frozen" includes rewards, fees and deposits while total frozen deposit is just deposits.

Comment: I see thank you, so I was confused by the frozen deposits and then seeing the individual frozen amounts. I am just trying to know what is the percentage frozen in the staking deposits, so the best KPI to track for this is "Total frozen deposits"